# File in xcode project not found

Tags: ios

I am getting an error:

> Error: Lexical or Preprocessor Issue: 'Constants.h' file not found

When the code is run, the issue disappears and the app works fine.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the file called `constants.h` or `Constants.h`?

Comment: Has it been dragged into your project as well?

Comment: Had this once, I suspect it is due to the indexing in xcode, I just closed and reopened xcode and it was gone.

Answer (score 0):

two things:

1. Do a product "clean" (CMD-SHIFT-K)
2. Avoid over-including headers from headers.

This involves using forward declarations whenever possible in headers (only #include another header if you are extending the class or implementing a protocol in that header). Use forward declarations for classes and protocols in your headers; then do the actual #import in your .m files.

```
@class SomeTypeINeedWhichIsAClass;
@protocol SomeProtocolWhichIsUsedInMyMethodSignatures;
```